# CollectionView Cell changes its width and height while loading Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view  that load dynamic content. when I am trying to load one of the cell is different in its height and width that I have set.
content mode of image view is AspectFit and drawing is set to clip to bounds.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "included", for: indexPath) as! IncludeCollectionViewCell

    let imagename = fabric[indexPath.row].fabricImage

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.junaidkk.com/images/fabric/thumb/"+imagename!)!
    print(url)

    cell.fabricImage.sd_setImage(with: url as URL!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default_logo"), options: .transformAnimatedImage, progress: nil, completed: nil)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat((collectionView.frame.size.width / 2) - 5), height: CGFloat(160))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

[image: see the screenshot]

Comment: You probably want `.aspectFill`, not `.aspectFit`

Comment: yes .aspectFill working nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using storyBoard, try this :

[image: CONTENT MODE]

Change `Aspect Fit` to `Aspect Fill` or try other options from the dropdown.

I believe `Aspect Fill` will solve your issue, as it did for me :)